# Adding space between two table of content entries

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I would like to add additional space between some selected ToC entries. 
I can achieve this by adding `\bigskip` in the title. While this produces the required output it also produces an error (associated with the hyperref package - see below).

So it seems there must be a more correct way of doing this.

What I want to achieve:
[image: What I want to achieve]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Summary\bigskip}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of contents}
\tableofcontents 

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of figures}
\listoffigures 

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of tables\bigskip}
\listoftables 

\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following error:

> Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `\@ifnextchar'
>
> Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing `\bigskipamount'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the space separately using

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\bigskip}
```

Your sample code:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\cleardoublepage % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Summary}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\bigskip} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\cleardoublepage % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of contents}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{-2ex}} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\tableofcontents 

\cleardoublepage % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of figures}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{-2ex}} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\listoffigures 

\cleardoublepage % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of tables}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\bigskip} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\listoftables 

\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, so simple!
Looking at it, it would be great to reduce the space between the ToC, LoF and LoT entries (for example to the same space as between section entries which is not shown in the MWE).

Comment: Should I add a new question for this/add this to my original question?

Comment: @Low You can also add negative space using `\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{-10pt}}` or something like that.

Comment: @Low I have updated my answer. Note that you have to add `\cleardoublepage` to make sure that the page references are correct. Without it, the `\tableofcontents` etc commands will start a new (double) page, but toc will contain the page number where the `\addtocontents` command was.

Comment: @Low Moreover, you have to add the command `\frontmatter`, otherwise you will have doubled page numbers, since `\mainmatter` resets page numbering. If you don't like roman numerals for the front matter, you have to make sure that page numbering continues for the main sections.

Comment: awesome! Wish I could double accept